# creating Graphs and charts in iphone application?

Tags: iphone

I saw a couple of applications in the itunes store with stunning visuals, how is it possible to create those graphs and charts.  I know these things can also be created using Java script, is javascript used to create them ?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

Answer (score 0):

you can draw chart's of your choice there is one API is available in Google for that using that API you van show your chart in UIWebView here I am providing the URL for that.That Url Required different kind of parameter for that.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=320x200&chd=t:315654000000,378799000000,421849000000&chxs=1N*cUSD&chxr=a&chds=a&chco=50b1c7,EBB671,DE091A&chbh=25,5,25&chxt=x,y,x,x&chxl=0:|2006|2008|2010|2:||5+Year+%+Sales+Growth++33%||3:||3+Year+%+Sales+Growth++11%||&chdl=Sales+Growth&chtt=Revenue+Trend&chts=000000,12,c

For More Detail please refer this URL: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/